# Writing an Appcelerator Titanium iOS module with 3rd party Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

I'm trying to write a new module with an external framework. I've followed the instructions here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Project-section-43288810_iOSModuleProject-AddaThird-PartyFramework on how to add an external frame work.

The module compiles. The Titanium app also compiles. But when inside the iPhone emulator the application crashes (even before using the module).

I'm getting the following error in Titnaium Studio:

```
[ERROR] :  An error occurred during build after 1m 19s 125ms
[ERROR] :  Detected multiple crashes:
[ERROR] :    /Users/ophir/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SweetAlertDialogTest_2015-11-05-193036_Ophirs-Mac-mini.crash
[ERROR] :    /Users/ophir/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SweetAlertDialogTest_2015-11-05-193042_Ophirs-Mac-mini.crash
[ERROR] :    /Users/ophir/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SweetAlertDialogTest_2015-11-05-193122_Ophirs-Mac-mini.crash
[ERROR] :    /Users/ophir/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SweetAlertDialogTest_2015-11-05-193354_Ophirs-Mac-mini.crash
[ERROR] :    /Users/ophir/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SweetAlertDialogTest_2015-11-06-064617_Ophirs-Mac-mini.crash
[ERROR] :    /Users/ophir/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SweetAlertDialogTest_2015-11-06-072141_Ophirs-Mac-mini.crash
[ERROR] :    /Users/ophir/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SweetAlertDialogTest_2015-11-06-072205_Ophirs-Mac-mini.crash
[ERROR] :    /Users/ophir/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SweetAlertDialogTest_2015-11-06-072249_Ophirs-Mac-mini.crash
[ERROR] :    /Users/ophir/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SweetAlertDialogTest_2015-11-06-073843_Ophirs-Mac-mini.crash
[ERROR] :  Note: these crashes may or may not be related to running your app.
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/ophir/.appcelerator/install/5.0.4/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:92:66)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
TRACE  | Sending exit signal to titanium process:  19220
```

I checked inside the crash log and this is what I get:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/SweetAlertFramework.framework/SweetAlertFramework
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6451C367-A7B7-437D-956F-57E86D8419FD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/683ED437-B0E6-42F0-BC8E-26B2E95829CA/SweetAlertDialogTest.app/SweetAlertDialogTest
  Reason: image not found
```

I've checked the path inside `module.xcconfig` and it's correct. Another thing that seems strange here is the path in the crash log `/Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6451C367-A7B7-437D-956F-57E86D8419FD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/683ED437-B0E6-42F0-BC8E-26B2E95829CA/SweetAlertDialogTest.app/SweetAlertDialogTest` which is not a valid path on my machine.

Why doesn't it find the module?

Answer (score 1):

I think @HansKnoechel meant to say `*.framework`, and `iphone/platform`.  That way, when the module is actually bundled, the framework will be included as well.  You can verify the framework is in the right place by checking the `modules/iphone/<YourModule>/<YourModuleVersion>/platform` directory.

Comment: Did that. I followed the instructions of the documentation. I also checked that when I add the module to my Titanium project the framework is included (without it, it does not compile in Appcelerator Studio). I also checked and doubled checked the framework search path as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bundle of the 3rd party framework could not be referenced. Make sure you copy the *.framework files into platform/ios so they will be compiled. Also check the Xcode settings "Link binary with libraries" and make sure it is listed there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Where do can I find the *.bundle file. Don't see such thing...

Comment: It is about the .framework files as @brianjd corrected.

Comment: It's there - I followed the instructions on the documentation page and that was part of it.